# adressing in can protocol and dbc format?

Tags: can-bus

Am I correct that in can ecus/nodes receive all mesaages on the bus, and they filter the messages by message ID? 
In my dbc file (when openend in vector canoe) I see node name and node address. What is this address good for?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

In CAN protocol messages are broadcasted to the bus. Each ECU is configured to receive only particular messages based on the CAN DBC. A DBC file contains details of all TX and RX messages for all nodes. These nodes are nothing but different ECUs. The address is used for arbitration on the bus. CAN uses CSMA/CA (Carrier Sense Multiple Access Collision Avoidance). So, if two ECUs want to send message at the same time, only one will be able to send based on arbitration.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I correct that in can ecus/nodes receive all mesaages on the bus, and they filter the messages by message ID?

Yes.

> In my dbc file (when openend in vector canoe) I see node name and node address. What is this address good for?

ID and address are the same thing. The name is just a help for humans beings.